# How to pass year as parameter to a SQL query using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm facing an issue when trying to pass year as parameters. I get

> Failed to convert the date and / or time from a string

See my code below

```
"SELECT distinct [study_patient_name],[study_patient_prenom] " +
"FROM examen where study_traitant_id='" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.Trim() + "'  "+
"and study_description ='"+GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text.Trim()+ "' "+
"and study_rv_date between ('01/01/@date1')  ('31/12/@date2')" +
"order by [study_patient_name] asc ", myConnection);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", txtdate1.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", txtdate2.Text);
```

Comment: Your code is *very* susceptible to [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you should fix it up!

Comment: It doesn't work like that - it won't inspect the content of strings, spot an `@` and decide to perform parameter replacement there. Any reason you can't compute complete `DateTime` values in C# code and pass those as parameters? (Also, if `study_rv_date` can contain a time component, it would be better to take out the `BETWEEN` and use explicit comparisons and an *exclusive* endpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to parameterize a query (you're doing it with 2 parameters already), so there is no excuse for string concatenation - it is a security hole. A big one!

That aside, you are looking for any date in range of given `YEAR`s. There's a [function for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186313.aspx)!

```
"and YEAR(study_rv_date) BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 "
```

Pass integers as the year.

Comment: i got this erroe The scalar variable "@ date2order" must be declared.!!

Comment: @gilas - neither your original question, nor my answer used a variable called `@date2order`. You've missed the space after `@date2` and before `order by`. d'oh!

Comment: and YEAR(study_rv_date) BETWEEN '"+ txtdate1.Text+"' AND '"+txtdate2.Text+"' ...thank you Jamiec

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to parameterize your queries. This is what your code should look like:

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [study_patient_name],[study_patient_prenom] " +
        "FROM examen WHERE study_traitant_id = @study_traitant_id " +
        "AND study_description = @study_description " +
        "AND study_rv_date BEWTWEEN @date1 AND @date2 " +
        "ORDER BY [study_patient_name]";

var myCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@study_traitant_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@study_description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text.Trim();
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
```

`year` here is your variable to be passed as a parameter, which you'll be getting from `txtDate1` and `txtDate2`. To get the start date, I used:

```
new Datetime(year, 1, 1);
```

and for end date:

```
new Datetime(year, 12, 31);
```

You may use other functions to your liking.

Additional note, it's better to use `Parameters.Add` instead of `AddWithValue`. According to [**this article**](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/):

> There is a problem with the AddWithValue() function: it has to infer
>   the database type for your query parameter. Here’s the thing:
>   sometimes it gets it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters from C# as follows:

```
        myCommand.CommandText = @"
            SELECT DISTINCT
                [study_patient_name], [study_patient_prenom] 
            FROM 
                [examen]
            WHERE 
                [study_traitant_id] = @TraitantId
                AND
                [study_description] = @Description
                AND
                [study_rv_date] BETWEEN @StartOfYear AND @EndOfYear
        ";

        // Send Parameters
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("TraitantId", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.Trim());
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text.Trim());
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartOfYear", new DateTime(int.Parse(txtdate1.Text), 1, 1));
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndOfYear", new DateTime(int.Parse(txtdate2.Text), 12, 31));
```